# How to use JQuery to detect Mouseover and add animation on dynamic item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a series of div's that get loaded dynamically. There ID is set when the page loads, and they all have the same class of "pp-post". When the user hovers over an item with class="pp-post" the 'p' items within that become visible.

I want to add a different animation for each of these 'p' tags when they become visible.

I have minimal experience with JQuery so I am wondering how I can detect which "pp-post" item is hovered and apply the animations to the 'p' tags.

As for the animations not sure yet what to use but it could be JQuery animations or maybe use animations.css and add a class to the p tags when visible.

HTML:

```
<div id="{post_id}" class="pp-post">
     <div id="{post_id}" class="pp-post-item">
             <p id="{post_id}" class="pp-post-title"></p>
             <p id="{post_id}" class="pp-arrow-down"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.pp-post-title {  
  visibility: hidden;
}

.pp-arrow-down {  
  visibility: hidden;
}

.pp-post-item:hover > p {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how I can detect which "pp-post" item is hovered and apply the animations to the 'p' tags

You can use `$(this)` to get the hovered `pp-post`.

The code will look like

```
$('.pp-post').hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        //animation code
    });
});
```

To make `p` tag visible,

```
$('pp-post').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('p').animate({
        //animation code
    });
});
```

Instead of `animation` function, you can also use certain specific functions like `fadeIn`

Sample snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.pp-post').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('p').fadeIn(2000);
  });
});
```

```css
.pp-post p {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pp-post">Hover
  <p>Sample1</p>
</div>
<div class="pp-post">Hover
  <p>Sample1</p>
</div>
<div class="pp-post">Hover
  <p>Sample1</p>
</div>
<div class="pp-post">Hover
  <p>Sample1</p>
</div>
<div class="pp-post">Hover
  <p>Sample1</p>
</div>
```